# Is a Boros Guildgate considered a mountain?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I ask this question because I don't know if we can enchant a guilgate, like a boros guildgate as example, with [Chained to the Rocks](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373521).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not. Mountain is a subtype of a land cards; for [Boros Guildgate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boros%20Guildgate), the subtype is "Gate".

However, [Steam Vents](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Steam%20Vents) is a mountain and can be enchanted with Chained to the Rocks, because it has subtypes "Island" and "Mountain".

Answer (score 2):

No.

"Mountain" can mean two things:

1. An object whose name is "Mountain". e.g. [Mountain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mountain)
2. An object which has the land (sub)type "Mountain". e.g. [Mountain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mountain) and [Steam Vents](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Steam%20Vents)

When a card refers to something that can be a name or a type, it always refers to the type<sup>[1]</sup>. As such, [Chained to the Rocks](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chained%20to%20the%20Rocks) looks for objects with the land type "Mountain".

For example,

- A [Mountain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mountain) does have that type. It can be enchanted by Chained to the Rocks.
- A [Mountain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mountain) enchanted by [Contaminated Ground](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Contaminated%20Ground) does not have that type. It is a Land, it is a Basic, and it is a Swamp, but it is not a Mountain (despite having that for name). It cannot be enchanted by Chained to the Rocks.
- A [Steam Vents](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Steam%20Vents) does have that type. It can be enchanted by Chained to the Rocks.
- A [Boros Guildgate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boros%20Guildgate) does not have that type. It is a Land, and it is a Gate, but it is not a Mountain. It cannot be enchanted by Chained to the Rocks.

---

1. For references to permanents, this is covered by 109.2.

   > 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.

   The same is understood to apply for references to non-permanents, though this is not explicitly stated in the rules.

Comment: i dont think 1. should be there, as you say it isnt in the comp rules. It just happens that all objects named mountain happen to also be basic land type mountain. it feels like saying that a creature called Instant could be countered by spell pierce. it doesnt actually matter, but it still feels wrong to me. I dont think any card exists that refers to mountain purely by name, and I dont think a card like that could ever be printed due to the templating of cards relying so heavily on mountain being used for the basic land type.

Comment: @Patters, "It just happens that all objects named mountain happen to also be basic land type mountain." That's not true. See second example in my post.

Comment: @Patters, Note (1) wasn't completely correct. Fixed.

Comment: @Patters, Such a card _could_ exist, templated either "card(s) named 'Mountain'" or "land(s) named 'Mountain'" (or similar). While no such card currently exists, it _could_, and there is already Extraplanar Lens which uses "a land with the same name as the imprinted card".